# How to unlock a phone from a specific mobile operator

Tags: lock-screen

When you want to dial a number it appears on the screen as such.  This device is locked to a specific mobile operator. Contact your mobile operator for the unlock code.

Comment: its a risky process, i suggest you try it in some nearby mobile shops, they will do it for you!